# Basic nodejs route resulting in 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to create two separate routes in NodeJS, I am using the express framework and angular on the client side. I am currently able to render my index page successfully by visiting `localhost:3000/` although when I try to render the login page by visiting `localhost:3000/login` I am getting a `GET /login 404` error and not sure why b/c I set it up extremely similar to the index route. Not sure if I missed something.

This my app.js

```
    //require dependencies 
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//require routes but do not user yet
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');

//start app
var app = express();


// view engine setup - default views directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.locals.delimiters = '<% %>';
app.set('view engine', 'hjs'); //use hogan templating for views

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/login', login);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
}); 

// error handlers
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/login.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', function(req, res){
   res.render('login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

views/login.hjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  HELLO WORLD
</body>
</html>
```

Visiting localhost:3000/login renders the following:

```
{{ message }}
{{ error.status }}

{{ error.stack }}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When writing `app.use('/login', login)`, you are telling Express to use your router under the *namespace* : '/login'; Therefore, all routes defined into **login.js** don't need this prefix.

Try to access `localhost:3000/login/login` ;)

Then, just change your router to:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `router.get('/', function (req, res) { ... })` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In that case, how come when I change `app.use('/login', login)` to `app.use('/', login)` and the router is `router.get('/login', function(req, res){...});`, the url: `localhost:3000/login` still results in an error?

Comment: +1, However, changing to `app.use('/login', login)` and having `router.get('/', function(req, res){...});` works well :) shouldn't both approaches work?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend : both way are corrects and work fine for me. Be sure to restart your server when you update routes :)

Comment: Really appreciate it! Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for too long ;) Thanks!